# Product table filtering with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working in an MVC application with an EF Code First back-end. I have a products table that I would like to paginate and filter by Category or Brand.

[image: data table with filter]

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is and feel free to point the sillyness of my way, but right now I have the following ViewModel for the above page:

```
public class InventoryReportViewModel
{
  public SearchViewModel Search { get; set; } // 2 string props [Type and Term]
  public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
  public PaginationViewModel Pagination { get; set; } // 3 int props [currentPage, recordsPerPage, totalRecords]
}
```

I'd like to be smart about how I structure my LINQ query and do not want to repeat myself, and here's my attempt:

```
public InventoryReportViewModel GetProducts(int page, string searchTerm, string searchType)
{
  var activeProducts = _context.Products.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
  {
    if (searchType == "category")
    {
      activeProducts.Where(
          p => string.Equals(p.Category.Name, searchTerm.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .OrderBy(p => p.Category.Name)
        .Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1))
        .Take(_recordsPerPage);
    }
    else
    {
      activeProducts.Where(
          p => string.Equals(p.Brand.Name, searchTerm.Trim(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1))
        .Take(_recordsPerPage);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    activeProducts.Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1)).Take(_recordsPerPage);
  }

  var productPageVm = new InventoryReportViewModel
  {
    Products = ProductViewModelFactory.BuildListOfProductViewModels(activeProducts),
    Pagination = new PaginationViewModel
    {
      CurrentPage = page,
      RecordsPerPage = _recordsPerPage,
      TotalRecords = _context.Products.Count(p => p.Quantity > 0 && !p.IsDeleted)
    }
  };
  return productPageVm;
}
```

But the above doesn't seem to work! I get 200 Products returned in the ViewModel when I should get only 10 since that is my `recordsPerPage`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where you are passing value to this recordsPerPage variable?

Comment: From web.config. I'm reading it in the constructor. I've debugged and can see that all my Pagination properties are what they should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LINQ methods do not modify the sequence which you apply them on, they produce new sequences as their return value. You need to use the return value of the LINQ operations! `activeProducts` will not be affected by your method calls.

Example:

```
var activeProducts = _context.Products.Where(p => !p.IsDeleted);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
{
  if (searchType == "category")
  {
      // See the change here?
      activeProducts = activeProducts
          .Where(p => string.Equals(
              p.Category.Name, 
              searchTerm.Trim(),
              StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
          .OrderBy(p => p.Category.Name)
          .Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1))
          .Take(_recordsPerPage);
  }
  else
  {
      // Here.
      activeProducts = activeProducts
        .Where(p => string.Equals(
            p.Brand.Name, 
            searchTerm.Trim(),
            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1))
        .Take(_recordsPerPage);
  }
}
else
{
    // And here.
    activeProducts = activeProducts
        .Skip(_recordsPerPage * (page - 1))
        .Take(_recordsPerPage);
}
```

Comment: So assign the modifications I'm doing to the LINQ to new variables?

Comment: You can re-assign to the `activeProducts` variable if you wish. Updated with an example.